# jQuery: $ not defined

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make simple jQuery click function. But this one dose not work. not even the simple alert. could you please assist me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ alert("JavaScript is working");
$("#tab").slideUp("fast");
$("#steps").click(function(){
$("#tab").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

If you think it is a link error then my all link go like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="divset.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="top.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="hint2.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

where divset.css, top.css and hint2.js are my css and jQuery documents.

Comment: Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="hint2.js"></script> ` after jQuery is added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your code after jquery libs.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hint2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the markup you have shared it looks like said script is in the file `hint2.js`, if so when that script is executed jQuery is not yet loaded that is the readon for the error so

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="divset.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="top.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hint2.js"></script>
```