# JavaScript Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript

I appreciate anyone help, here is my problem

I have a register.php file and a main.js file

When the form is submitted, I get a console error

The error is at the main.js file on line 4 which is the  "$(document)" portion of the code below

The form name is "`<form class="uk-form-stacked js-register">`" and is located at the registration.php file

main.js  code

```
$(document)
.on("submit", "form.js-register", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert ('form was submitted'); 

    
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery in the HTML

Comment: add jquery CDN.

Comment: The registration.php has a link to a footer.php file that loads                                                                                                       <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Comment: Your JS is running before jQuery is loaded. Move jQuery to the header or move your JavaScript after jQuery

Comment: It worked,  Awsome that was simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: $ not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205221/jquery-not-defined)